# speech recognition python3.4 with pocketsphinx

Tags: speech-recognition, python-3.4, pocketsphinx

i just following this >> [steps](https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx/) << and works well,

now, how do i get started with python?
i tried this code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

# obtain audio from the microphone
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say something!")
    audio = r.listen(source)

# recognize speech using Sphinx
try:
    print("Sphinx thinks you said " + r.recognize_sphinx(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Sphinx could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Sphinx error; {0}".format(e))
```

and got an error:

`Sphinx error; missing PocketSphinx module: ensure that PocketSphinx is set up correctly.`

speech_recognition already installed, but i'm not sure with pocketsphinx and sphinxbase. everything i did just following: https://cmusphinx.github.io/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pocketsphinx RequestError: missing PocketSphinx module: ensure that PocketSphinx is set up correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523705/python-pocketsphinx-requesterror-missing-pocketsphinx-module-ensure-that-pocke)

Comment: it said "Requirement already satisfied: pocketsphinx in c:\python34\lib\site-packages" , or where i can find pocketsphinx package?, i'm running on windows

Comment: Most likely you are trying to run speech_recognition with python2 while you installed pocketsphinx for python3. You need to make sure you have just a single python version.

Comment: i'm sure it was running on python3 and installed for python3, there was some problem when i install pocketsphinx, i need something called swig for install pocketsphinx by pip, how can i get that swig?,

Comment: swig is available on http://swig.org

Answer (score 1):

You need to `pip install PocketSphinx` which depends on the binary SWIG package. For Windows the SWIG instructions are in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7443238/623735).

For OSX there are additional requirements:

```
$ brew install cmu-pocketsphinx
$ brew install portaudio
$ brew install swig
$ pip install PocketSphinx
```