# Sphinx error; missing PocketSphinx module: ensure that PocketSphinx is set up correctly

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, pocketsphinx

I tried to use the explanation: [Python pocketsphinx RequestError: missing PocketSphinx module: ensure that PocketSphinx is set up correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523705/python-pocketsphinx-requesterror-missing-pocketsphinx-module-ensure-that-pocke)

So I installed the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install -qq python python-dev python-pip build-essential swig libpulse-dev
```

But I got the same error by running functions from SpeechRecognition after installation:
Sphinx error; missing PocketSphinx module: ensure that PocketSphinx is set up correctly

I use the following versions:

Name: pocketsphinx
Version: 0.1.15
Summary: Python interface to CMU Sphinxbase and Pocketsphinx libraries
Home-page: https://github.com/bambocher/pocketsphinx-python
Author: Dmitry Prazdnichnov
Author-email: dmitry@prazdnichnov.name
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:

Name: SpeechRecognition
Version: 3.8.1
Summary: Library for performing speech recognition, with support for several engines and APIs, online and offline.
Home-page: https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition#readme
Author: Anthony Zhang (Uberi)
Author-email: azhang9@gmail.com
License: BSD
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but maybe someone will use the explanation
First try:

```
sudo apt-get install -qq python python-dev python-pip build-essential swig libpulse-dev
```

Then install the following package:

```
sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev
```

And then run:

```
pip install PocketSphinx
```